# 960 grid with slider, looking for way to make slider span entire 960

Tags: css, 960.gs, nivo-slider

I'm using the 960 grid with 12 columns and Nivo slider.

I'm using the 'grid_12' as my DIV but I'd like to find a way to make the slider consume the entire 960 grid (instead of 940) thus eliminating the 10px border that is on each side of the slider.

Comment: Did you try adding both `alpha` and `omega` to the class list for the containing element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your div container element like so:

```
<div class="grid_12 alpha omega">
// slider
</div>
```

alpha / omega are used to eliminate padding (10px from left/right respectively)

Comment: I had initially thought that but for some reason when I tried it earlier, using both alpha and omega didn't effect it.

Answer (score 0):

Is there padding on your container div or a margin on the slider div?